# Build Slidify Package from Source

Tags: r, github, package

Is anyone else having issues build the slidify package from github.  I want to play around but the install returns an error.  Here are the commmands I used and resulting error:

```
> library(devtools)
Rtools not on path and not installed in default location.
Warning message:
package ‘devtools’ was built under R version 2.14.2 
> install_github('slidify', 'ramnathv')
Installing github repo(s) slidify/master from ramnathv
Installing slidify.zip from https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/zipball
Installing slidify
* checking for file 'C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsrQIgw\ramnathv-slidify-954647c/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'slidify':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
Warning in .write_description(db, ldpath) :
  Unknown encoding with non-ASCII data: converting to ASCII
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'slidify_0.1.tar.gz'
 ERROR
packaging into .tar.gz failed
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-214~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD build "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsrQIgw\ramnathv-slidify-954647c" --no-manual --no-vignettes' had status 1
```

I am on Windows 7, but here is my session info just in case:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_0.6 plyr_1.7.1   RODBC_1.3-4 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] RCurl_1.9-5.1 tools_2.14.1
```

UPDATE:  After updating to R 2.15.0, I get the following error (even after install Rtools):

```
Warning: invalid package 'Files/R/R-2.15.0/library'
Error: ERROR: cannot cd to directory 'C:/Program'
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.0/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8oMxGU/slidify_0.1.tar.gz --library=C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.0/library' had status 1
```

Comment: I developed `slidify`. I am on a Mac, so am not really sure what the issue could be. I will see if I can find a windows machine to build and figure out what the problem is. Based on your error message, it looks like an `rtools` installation issue. Maybe somebody on the `devtools` mailing list or on `github` can help.

Comment: Worked great on a Mac....unfortunately I use a Windows machine at work.  Thanks for putting this together, I have been waiting for something like it for a while now.

Comment: I'm on Windows7 right now and it installs fine.  Btibert3 I think the problem is that you're running 2.14 while slidify has R (>= 2.15.0) as a dependency.

Comment: @Ramnath What is creating the dependency on >= 2.15?

Comment: do a pull and maybe try the `build_win()` function in `devtools`? I'm on a mac and it installs fine for me so I can't help much either.

Comment: @Maiasaura: run build_win, I get the exact error message of 'ERROR
packaging into .tar.gz failed'

Answer (score 2):

You're running R 2.14.1 (according to your SessionInfo).  slidify has R (>= 2.15.0) as a dependency so you won't be able to install it as is.  I would suggest upgrading to 2.15 if possible.

I tried getting it to work with 2.14.1 and it just wasn't happening.  It worked quite nicely with 2.15 though.

<s>I don't know what exactly depends on R 2.15 but it's possible that ramnathv put that as the dependency just to be safe.  I forked it and reduced the dependency to 2.14 (`install_github('slidify', 'Dasonk')`) and it installs fine on my copy of R2.14.1 but I haven't actually tested out any of the functions.</s>

So if you can't update R you can try to grab it from my fork or if you have a github account you could fork it yourself and then change the dependency.  If there really are features that require 2.15 you could try to figure out a way around those and then send a pull request to ramnathv.

Comment: Yes. I put 2.15.0 just to be safe. Now that you mention it, I don't see any reason why it wont work with 2.14.1, unless one of the dependencies needs 2.15.0. I will check and modify the requirements accordingly.

Comment: I didn't see a requirement of 2.15 in any of the dependencies when I checked but like I said in my answer I tried to get things to work and with 2.14 I got some errors and with 2.15 everything worked fine.

Comment: interesting. wonder what changed between 2.14 and 2.15 that makes things different. does the issue persist on macs too?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but after going to 2.15, I am getting the error outlined above (after update).  It worked fine on my mac, but I am hoping to take advantage of this at work.

Comment: @Btibert3 what version of Rtools are you using? I'm using 2.15.0.1911 and it works fine in R 2.15.0.

Comment: Rtools version 2.15.0.1919  --- at this point, I feel like this is something that I am doing, yet, I am not sure what else to do.